# Issue while passing the dynamic path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have tried many ways and spent a lot of time to pass my dynamic context path, but it is showing some syntax error. My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    Test.MODEL.HTMLVideoElement('demo', '/images/blue.jpg');
    Test.MODEL.videoControls();
    Test.LOGIC.APP();
});
```

In the above code I need to pass the dynamic path in place of `'/images/blue.jpg'`. The dynamic path is `${context}${Test.bgImage.imagePath}`

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Are you using ES6 standard code? `${context}${Test.bgImage.imagePath}` seems string interpolation syntax in ES6 or i suspect this is something like `JSTL` code.

Comment: `${context}${Test.bgImage.imagePath}` then what is it?

Comment: Hmm... i suspected it. see the comment above.

Comment: In this ${context}${Test.bgImage.imagePath} path I am getting the required dynamic path. Now how can I pass it as the parameter in HTMLVideoElement();

Answer (score 0):

See if you are on the standards of unobtrusive javascript then what you can do is just use a script block before inclusion of ready script.

So, on the jsp you can create a script block:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var obj = {
         context : '${context}',
         imagePath : '${Test.bgImage.imagePath}'
    };
</script>
```

Now in the ready script you can refer to this `obj`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    Test.MODEL.HTMLVideoElement('demo', obj.context + '/' + imagePath ); //<---use here
    Test.MODEL.videoControls();
    Test.LOGIC.APP();
});
```

---

Or you can make use of `data-*` attributes on the element itself like:

```
<video id='demo' data-context='${context}' data-imgpath='${Test.bgImage.imagePath}'>
</video>
```

Then in the script you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var ctx = $('#demo').data('context'); // get context
    var imgpath = $('#demo').data('imgpath'); // get imgpath
    Test.MODEL.HTMLVideoElement('demo', ctx + '/' + imgpath ); //<---use here
    Test.MODEL.videoControls();
    Test.LOGIC.APP();
});
```